# How do I move a file to a directory and not replacing a file?

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, directory

I'm trying to move a file from the desktop to a directory called "Textfiles" but every time I try to it gives me this error.

> Additional information: The target file  "C:\Users\Developer\Documents\Textfiles" is a directory, not a file.

Now I know that using

```
File.Copy(fileName, targetPath);
```

Would be wrong and that's what I am using right now, It takes two parameters, the first being the file yopu want to copy and the second one being the file it's replacing? Correct me if i am wrong on the second parameter.

Anyways, I tried `System.IO.Directory.Move(fileName, destFile);` aswell but that pretty much gave me the same error.

The two parameters are very simple, just two string that consists of paths.

```
string fileName = filePath.ToString();
string targetPath = @"C:\Users\Developer\Documents\Textfiles";
```

What would be the correct way to transfer fileName to targetPath ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the destination filename.

```
string fileOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
string targetPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Developer\Documents\Textfiles", fileOnly);
System.IO.File.Move(fileName, targetPath);
```

Comment: What if I dont want to hardcode the path? Cant I do something like..
string path =Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

Answer (score 2):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx

for documentation:

```
destFileName
Type: System.String
The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory or an existing file.
```

You have to add the new file name to the destination directory.

You can get the file name with:

```
result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

thus in your case:

```
string targetPath = @"C:\Users\Developer\Documents\Textfiles\" + Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

Comment: What if I dont want to hardcode the path? Cant I do something like..
string path =Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

Comment: Yes as long as the path is a file name and not a folder name.